# Can not Export SharePoint 2013 list to MS Access

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

When attempting to exporting a list I get the error message -

> "Export to Database Failed.  To export a list you must have a MS
>   SharePoint Foundation compatible application."

Note we have SharePoint 2013 and MS Office 2010. If I click on export to Excel I have no issues.

I was told that the reason this occurs is because I do not have MS Access 2013, but to me that makes no sense.  If I can export a list to Excel and we have Office 2010 which includes MS Access 2010 and MS Excel 2010 why do I get this error message?

What is my resolution.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried it in IE. sometime other browser doesn't support this functionality. If issue happens with all browsers then check this [article](http://blogs.technet.com/b/office_integration__sharepoint/archive/2014/02/24/quot-to-export-a-list-you-must-have-a-microsoft-sharepoint-foundation-compatible-application-quot.aspx).